# Android regular expression

Tags: android, regex

I have searched a lot for a regular expression or pattern that would work for me, but I haven't found any.

In a Edit text I want to allow first 4 digit and then 2 uppercase letters, so Ihave created a pattern:

```
private final Pattern sPattern  = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{0,4}[A-Z]{0,2}");
```

But it allows first 2 capital letters, too.

If i change my pattern to

```
private final Pattern sPattern  = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{0,4}[A-Z]{4,6}");
```

I am not able to get anything rright.

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what `{4,6}` means?

Comment: I think position from and to.

Comment: @Amee: `{4,6}` is a limiting quantifier that matches the preceding subpattern 4, 5 or 6 times. It has nothing to do with positions in string.

Comment: @Amee Then you should probably get your hands on a regex tutorial or book, and start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with limiting quantifier. Just remove `0,` as it allows less than 4 digits or 2 uppercase letters:

```
^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}
```

This will require 4 digits at the beginning and 2 letters after.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE1zZ6/1)

For live validation, you can use

```
^[0-9]{0,4}(?:(?<=[0-9]{4})[A-Z]{0,2})?
```

It will allow a user to input 0 to 4 digits and then 0 to 2 English uppercase letters *only if* there are 4 digits before them. Mind that if the input can contain just these max 6 characters, you can add the `$` end-of-string anchor at the end.

Comment: Note that you cannot use 1 regex for both live input validation and final input validation. `^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}` is the regex to be used when the textbox loses focus (final validation). Your regex is quite fine for live validation, but you might want to check for at least 1 digit before a letter with `^[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]{0,2}`, or use a look-around to disallow only letters at the beginning: `^[0-9]{0,4}(?<=[0-9])[A-Z]{0,2}`.

Comment: hello Stribizhev , This pattern allow me to add like 34AS also, I use this pattern ^[0-9]{0,4}(?<=[0-9])[A-Z]{0,2}

Comment: Sure it will. So, you want to use the regex for live validation, and the number of digits in the beginning must be exactly 4, right? And then a user should be able to type only 2 letters, right? Try `^[0-9]{0,4}(?:(?<=[0-9]{4})[A-Z]{0,2})?`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, Can u give any link or tutorial so that i can learn how to make regular expression???

Comment: You can learn a lot at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), and use [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) or [ocpsoft](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/) to quickly check simple regex patterns.

Comment: Can u please  suggest pattern for total 30 character , first 10 digit,10 upper letter, 10 lower letter.???

Comment: i want like "9999999999AAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaa"

Comment: Please help for this kind of pattern..  "9999999999AAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaa"

Comment: it's not working, not allow to right any thing. first 10 character only, second 10 character uppercase letter only and third 10 character is lower case only.

Comment: Just add the `$` end of string anchor at the end: : [`^[0-9]{10}[A-Z]{10}[a-z]{10}$`](https://regex101.com/r/dQ3kF0/2)

Comment: Then, you need to provide exact requirements, I do not know what is meant by "does not work". You must be specific to get appropriate help.

Comment: I want to allow only 30 character in edit text, First 10 character will be digits only, Second 10 character will be Upper case letter, Third 10 character will be lower char, Output should like  "9999999999AAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaa" ,  IT should not be like "11aaAA22FFss55as89HJ78KKKlll90hu."

Comment: @ stribizhev , Is there any  Api avilable in android which gives Regular expression in responce???

Comment: I do not know if such API exists at all. Do you need the regex for *live* validation of that potentially 30-char string?

Comment: Yes, I want to create regular expression dynamically as per web service response,  So if any  Api or class available which give me pattern from the string so it will be most helpful for me.  Currently i need regex for live validation of that potentially 30-char string.

Comment: Well, using the same technique (making next subpattern optional with a lookbehind in front to check if any of the preceding subpattern match), here it is: [`^[0-9]{0,10}(?:(?<=[0-9])[A-Z]{0,10})?(?:(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]{0,10})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/dQ3kF0/3).

Comment: @ stribizhev Edittext do not allow me to right any thing by using   "^[0-9]{0,10}(?:(?<=[0-9])[A-Z]{0,10})?(?:(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]{0,10})?$."

Comment: I see you already asked a question. Perhaps, some one will come up with an idea. Building patterns based on strings is not an easy thing. I have no idea why it does not work for you, it works well at regex101.com and the expression is compatible with Android regex.